# Is there a reason why $\log \phi \approx (\log 2)^2$?

Tags: logarithms, approximation, golden-ratio

With $\phi=\frac{\sqrt5+1}2$ the golden ratio, we have
$$\log_2 \phi = 0.6942\ldots\\
\,\log_e 2 = 0.6931\ldots$$

Equivalently,

$$2^{\log 2} =1.6168\ldots\\ 
 \quad\;\phi = 1.6180\ldots$$

Is it a simple coincidence or is there a deeper reason for this?

To give an idea of the sort of thing I'm looking for, the identity $\frac{1/\sqrt2}2 = \sinh \frac{\log 2}{2}$ is a very good explanation of the observation that $1/\sqrt2 \approx \log 2$. It also allows estimating the error term by expanding the series for $\sinh$.

Edit: Expanding on infinitylord's remark, this equivalent to the observation

$$0.49915\ldots = \sinh\left((\log 2)^2\right)\approx 1/2$$

Comment: It's depend on the problem, which we need to solve.

Comment: I think that I would to see them a lot closer before I got very interested.

Comment: Do you like $\frac{\sqrt5+1}{2}\sim \frac{987}{610}$ too?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: It's a soft question, but to make it a little bit more formal I could ask: "Is there any algebraic equality that could help derive the bound $|(\log 2)^2 - \log \phi| < 1/1000$ or even $1/500$ without resorting to direct calculation of both terms?"

Comment: @badjohn: This is 12 times more accurate than $1/\sqrt2\approx \log 2$, yet there is a good explanation for that. But I agree a coincidence is perfectly possible.

Comment: @Math-fun: No, such identities are very common because you have 6 decimal digits to choose from in the fraction. The formula in the title has far less "entropy".

Comment: As an alternative view, $\log(\phi) - \log(2)^2 = \text{csch}(2)^{-1} - 4 (\coth(3)^{-1})^2 $

Comment: Of course, you may find it interesting if you wish.  I was just thinking that if you go out hunting for near misses then you are likely find many.  For example, I saw an exercise which searched for correlations among diverse data.  It found lots of close correlations between amusing data sets.

Comment: One (rough) way to do it: we have $\frac{5}{4} = \cosh(\log(2)) \approx 1 + \log^2(2)/2 + \log^4(2)/4!$ so  $\log^2(2) \approx \frac{\sqrt{1+1/6}-1}{1/6}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} = \cosh(\log(\phi)) \approx 1 + \log^2(\phi)/2$ so $\log(\phi) \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{1 + 1/4}-1}{1/4}}$. Since $\frac{\sqrt{1+h}-1}{h}\approx \frac{1}{2}$ when $h$ is small we get $\log^2(2) \approx \log(\phi)$.

Comment: It is easy to find a lot of very accurate coincidences, for example :
$$\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\simeq 1.618033988..$$
$$\cos(\sqrt{2}\:e^{-2})-\cos(\sqrt[3]{2}\:e^\pi) \simeq 1.618033988..$$
$$\sqrt{\cosh(\gamma)+\cos(\gamma)}-\frac{\gamma^3}{\sin(5)}\simeq 1.618033988..$$
$$\cosh\left(G^2\sinh(1)\right)+\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{\pi}}{\cos(3)}\right)\simeq 1.618033988..$$
$\gamma=$Euler-Masheroni constant $\quad;\quad G=$Catalan's constant.

From the paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14161596/Mathematiques-experimentales , where it is shown how to compute such  false equalities.

Comment: On the other hand there are some equalities that have an underlying "reason". So [almost integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_integer) on Wikipedia for a few.

Answer (score 4):

Take a few well-known constants such as $\gamma,1,\phi,2,e,3,\pi$, a few functions $\log,\exp,\sin,\cos$ and the six basic operations $+,-,\times,\div,a^b,\sqrt[b]a$. Form as many simple expressions as you can by combining them. For example, there are more than $6000$ expressions of the form $f(x)\text{ op }g(y)$ many of which fall in a small range, say $[0.1,10]$. Hence you can expect a few pseudo-coincidences.

Below a plot of the values of $2717$ such expressions with a value in the above range.

[image]

This exhaustive search reveals the interesting

$$\frac{e^\gamma}{e^e}\approx\frac{e}{e^\pi}$$
$$0.117529\approx0.117467$$

which is nothing but $$\gamma-e+\pi\approx 1.$$ (Actually $1.00052649003$.)

Comment: pretty neat! how did you draw that?

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki Excel.

Comment: +1 I've made some minor edits for brevity. Can you give a few more examples from your search?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: brevity ? Who cares ?